# Получить данные подов из кластера kubernetes

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, kubernetes

Есть .gitlab-ci.yml с выкладкой проекта на сервер с kubernetes

```
image: docker:stable

stages:
  - deploy

variables:
  REGISTRY_URL: https://$DOCKER_REGISTRY

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  when: manual
  tags:
    - docker-runner
  environment:
    name: test-server
  before_script:
    - apk add --no-cache curl
    - curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/$(curl -s https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl
    - chmod +x ./kubectl
  script:
    - echo $KUBECONFIG
    - export KUBECONFIG=$KUBECONFIG
    - ./kubectl create secret docker-registry gitlab-registry --docker-server=$REGISTRY_URL --docker-username=$DOCKER_USER --docker-password=$DOCKER_PASSWORD --dry-run=client -o yaml | ./kubectl apply -f -
    - ./kubectl apply -f manifests/service1/deployment.yaml
    - ./kubectl apply -f manifests/service2/deployment.yaml
    - ./kubectl rollout restart deployment
```

Как можно узнать состояние подов из гитлаба?

Перезапуск подов занимает время и сразу узнать это не получается, приходится заходить на сервер и смотреть что поднялось, а что не поднялось и почему.

Было бы неплохо хотябы знать что все поды работают.

Answer (score 0):

Кстати как вариант сделать подобную manual вещь в .gitlab-ci.yml

```
info:
  stage: info
  when: manual
  tags:
    - docker-runner
  environment:
    name: test-server
  before_script:
    - apk add --no-cache curl
    - curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/$(curl -s https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl
    - chmod +x ./kubectl
  script:
    - echo $KUBECONFIG
    - export KUBECONFIG=$KUBECONFIG
    - ./kubectl create secret docker-registry gitlab-registry --docker-server=$REGISTRY_URL --docker-username=$DOCKER_USER --docker-password=$DOCKER_PASSWORD --dry-run=client -o yaml | ./kubectl apply -f -
    - ./kubectl get deployment
    - ./kubectl get svc
    - ./kubectl get pods
```